# It is possible to make an IPSEC VPN Bonding?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, tunneling

I wanted to know if It is possible to bound two IPSEC tunnels ? I've already done a VPN bonding of SSH tunnels, but It will be better if I use IPSEC.

Comment: Please don't [cross-site post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198121/it-is-possible-to-make-an-ipsec-vpn-bonding).  If a site thinks that your question is better off somewhere else it will be migrated by a moderator.

Comment: This is off topic for IT security. But as a short answer, yes this can be done.